# Properties of Unbounded function

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is bounded on $A$ and $g$ is unbounded on $A$ then how can I prove that $f+g$ is unbounded on $A$?

Since $f$ is bounded then there exist $M>0$ such that $|f(x)| \le M\  \forall x\in A$ and $g$ is unbounded means $\exists M'>0$ such that $|g(x)| > M'\ \forall x\in A$.

Then what about $|(f+g) (x)|$?

Comment: Did you mean “constructing”?

Comment: yes. like by giving an example

Comment: But providing an example does not show that it is **always** true. So, what's the point?

Comment: you might have a really hard time proving this statement

Comment: Can you give me some hints .

Comment: well, its just not always true. think of an unbounded function and then think about what you could add to it to get zero perhaps

Comment: @CSquared You are wrong. It **is** always true.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos ah, i misread the statement. my apologies. i thought it read unbounded + unbounded is always unbounded

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos  yes. I see this.  Can you give some hints for how to show that it is always true?.

Comment: @SkMdSalauddin Can you edit your question and add to it your attempts?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ok done. Now see the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote, since $f$ is bounded, there is some $M>0$ such that $(\forall x\in A):|f(x)|<M$. Since $g$ is unbounded, for any $n\in\Bbb N$, there is some $a_n\in A$ such that $|g(a_n)|\geqslant n$. So$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N):|(f+g)(a_n)|=|g(a_n)+f(a_n)|\geqslant n-M.$$So, $\lim_{n\to\infty}|(f+g)(a_n)|=\infty$, and therefore $f+g$ is unbounded.